# How to Get Memory & CPU usage of Tomcat local server via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, tomcat, monitoring

I'm building a Nodejs App that will monitor the performance of a local tomcat server.The two server are running on the same machine.
I want to know several info about my Java ee App and tomcat server like CPU & Memory usage(Generaly important resource)
I have tried os-utils module but it return the ressource used by my node server.

```
const os = require('os-utils');   
os.cpuUsage(c => console.log( 'CPU Usage (%): ' + c ));
```

It is a method to use the os module for nodejs to return the resource of another server running on same machine ?

```
const os = require('os');
os.cpus()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Node.js, and `os-utils` refers to Node.js process itself.

There are third-party packages that can do that. [`pidusage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pidusage) is a wrapper around `ps` and `wmic` commands depending on the platform, it parses their output and is capable of providing stats on CPU and RAM process use based on its PID.

Comment: The `pidusage ` with the `find-process` package are helpful and give me what I need, but I want to know how to perform these result in real time on my front-end dashboard, I'm using React... thks for your help

Comment: This wasn't mentioned in original question, and the question is too broad in this form. You set up Node web server, likely Express, then do REST/AJAX request to it from React app. You may want to use web sockets instead of REST depending on how often you want to update this on client side.

Comment: thks @estus , your answer is helpful :) , I will try using fetch method or socket.io